# Opera Browser: prevent mousewheel scrolling?

Tags: css, browser, scroll, opera, mousewheel

I just buit a website that works good on any browser even ipad but in Opera I noticed a weird thing:

The website is built with a div layer on top z-index:999, body is overflow:hidden, and you can't scroll, but underneath the div there is a long text that goes way underneath the viewport...

The strage thing is that even if in any browser I was able to keep this effect, in Opera if I use the mousewheel you can keep scrolling...!
...argh..

do you know any hack/solution for this?

Comment: Can you give a link to the website you're talking about? It's hard to see exactly what you've done this way.

Comment: i know I'm sorry but is a website in our company server not accessible form outside...But you can think about this example: you have a long page in a blog, when you click a thumbnail it opens a fullscreen image (fullscreen related to the browser viewport) and i don't want the user to scroll down...i solved it in every new browser but Opera! :(

Comment: Hm.. We (Opera) fixed similar problems in the past, it would be interesting to see this one "live" to see if it's a new variation of those old bugs. Perhaps you could save the page (in internet archive / mht format) and E-mail me on hallvord at opera.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try catching the "DOMMouseScroll" event and stop the default event:

```
event.preventDefault(); // or return false
```

Comment: yep, i tried that, in factis what i'm using to prevent the ipad/iphone to scroll..but Opera still does it...i think i'm gonna drop the idea to make it for opera..

Comment: the iphone/ipad has another event, it's touchMove ;)